# Can I replace default validation message for integer field in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.net MVC - Custom attribut error message with nullable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134388/asp-net-mvc-custom-attribut-error-message-with-nullable-properties)

Can I replace default validation message for integer field? I want to localize it.
(For int: "The field Id must be a number.")

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ErrorMessageResourceName property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomeResource")]
[StringLength(30, ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomeOtherResource")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

You may checkout this [blog post](http://helios.ca/2010/02/17/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation-with-localization/) for an example.

In response to this

> How can I apply it for integer validation?

Firstly how are you validating integers ? Show us some code.

If your are using Regular expressions then use

```
 [RegularExpression("pattern", ErrorMessageResourceName = "SomeResource")]
```

or if you are using a custom attribute, you can use this in similar fashion.

Comment: How can I apply it for integer validation?